# LowLevelFatalError Game Crashes

Tags: windows-10

I'm getting this error in a bunch of games that randomly crash. Sounds like an Unreal Engine crash, it's happened in:

- The Ascent
- Kena Bridge of Spirits
- It Takes Two

The usual error message is:
`LowLevelFatalError [File:Unknown] [Line: 3971] Retry was NOT sucessful.`

Any ideas?

Some specific crash logs recently from The Ascent:

```
LowLevelFatalError [File:Unknown] [Line: 3971] Retry was NOT sucessful.

TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
kernel32
ntdll

---
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION

TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
kernel32
ntdll

---
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION 0x00007ff7e6b84000

TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
TheAscent_Win64_Shipping
kernel32
ntdll
```

Comment: Especially the illegal instruction error message is interesting. There are two possible reasons: the first is that your CPU is older and the game uses instructions that your CPU does not understand. But I don't think the game developers made such a mistake, therefore the second option is that because of an unknown reason the CPU instructions executed are not the one saved in the game exe file. That would mean they change somewhere between the storage and the CPU. Possible reasons are defect cables in case it is an HDD or SATA SSD. Also possible is a defect RAM module.

Comment: The game is installed on a PCIE SSD so no cables there, RAM could be faulty I guess, will run Windows Memory Diagnostics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PC initially had 16GB of DDR4. I bought what I thought was an identical kit of 16GB more DDR4, but apparently the revision number on the sticks were different. This apparently does not play nice with XMP, which was what was causing these super random infuriating crashes with this, among other games. Disabling XMP / removing the new DDR4 made these go away.